# How to add more information to Prometheus Gauge?

Tags: go, prometheus

I want to monitor the statistics of different subprocesses that are running in pods in different namespaces with Prometheus and I am looking for a way to properly expose this information.

My cluster is similar to below:

```
cluster
├── ns1
│   ├── ns1-pod1
│   │   ├── proc-p1-1
│   │   └── proc-p1-2
│   └── ns1-pod2
│       ├── proc-p2-1
│       └── proc-p2-2
└── ns2
    ├── ns2-pod1
    │   ├── proc-p1-1
    │   └── proc-p1-2
    └── ns2-pod2
        ├── proc-p2-1
        └── proc-p2-2
```

Each pod is publishing the statistics of its processes to RabbitMQ with a specific routing key and I can read the statistics from there.

I wrote an exporter that can connect to RMQ in one namespace, read the statistics and expose them on the `/metrics` so Prometheus can read it. An example of my exporter:

```golang
// prometheus go client
var MemoryValue = prometheus.NewGauge(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: namespace,
        Name:      "MemoryValue",
        Help:      "MemoryValue",
    })

prometheus.MustRegister(MemoryValue)
MemoryValue.Set(opst.Memory.Value) // "opst.Memory.Value" is what I get from RMQ
```

The problem is I don't know how to label the metrics for each process in a pod. I mean, for example, at the moment I have 4 processes in ns1 but I am exposing all of them on `MemoryValue`. I need a way similar to `Namespace` to label each process by pod and process names (I have this information but how to add them to Prometheus?).

Comment: Use, well, labels: [GaugeVec](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#GaugeVec).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Prometheus and I didn't know about the GaugeVec. Please post your answer as a solution so I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter correctly mentioned the solution is to use `GaugeVec`:

```golang
var CpuPercentValue = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
    prometheus.GaugeOpts{
        Namespace: "MyExporter",
        Name:      "CpuPercentValue",
        Help:      "CpuPercentValue",
    },
    []string{
        "namespace",
        "proc_qID",
        "opID",
    },
)

CpuPercentValue.With(prometheus.Labels{"namespace": namespace, "proc_qID": procid, "opID": opid}).Set(opst.CpuPercent.Value)
```